# Program is not giving the expected output

Tags: c, getchar

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {

    enum loop {NO ,YES};
    enum loop okloop = YES;
    int i=0;

    char s[8];
    int lim=6;
    char c;

    while (okloop==YES)
    {
        if (i>=lim-1)
            okloop=NO;
        else if ((c=getchar())!='\n')
            okloop=NO;
        else if (c==EOF)
            okloop=NO;
        else {
            s[i]=c;
            ++i;
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<5;++i)
        printf("this is the character %c\n",s[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

I am just inputing a character from the keyboard and stored it in an array; and then I have to print the character stored in the array to screen, but the output is not as I have expected.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. As it stands it's unreadable.

Comment: ... and what are you expecting - kittens?

Comment: Hint: `getchar()` returns `int`, not `char`.

Comment: I want to store character in an array and want to print the character stored in array to the screen

Comment: I formatted your code, but next time please take some time, and indent your code properly before asking a question.

Comment: @meskobalazs: Did you?

Comment: @SouravGhosh , It's still un-indented. Also,why did you add the [tag:scanf] tag? There isn't a single `scanf` in this post.

Comment: @CoolGuy I curse the non-responding save-edit button on my pc.

Comment: I did, but someone else also did

Comment: @alk , [meskobalazs](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2102532/meskobalazs)'s edits need to be peer reviewed as he has <2K rep. Someone(Probably SouravGhosh) who has >2K rep might've edited it before his edit was approved.

Comment: Yes, that was the case, I resubmitted my edit, it is now approved

Comment: "The output is not what I expected". What is it, and what did you expect?

Comment: Again: This `else if (c==EOF)` will never evaluate to be true.

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding, you need to change

```
else if ((c=getchar())!='\n')
```

to

```
else if ((c=getchar()) == '\n')
```

Otherwise, you'll end up storing nothing *valid* in `s[i]`.

Also, as a sidenote

1. Always initialize the local variables.
2. add a `return 0;` in your `main()`.
3. think of null terminating `s[i]` after reading inputs, just in case you want to use it as a *string* later.

Good practice.

Comment: The`0`-termination is not necessary here, as the `char`-array is treated as plain `char`-array only, not as a C-"string".

Comment: @alk Absolutely sir, just as a reference for future use. Was updating my answer. :-)

Comment: The "*good practise*" is to initialise your variables! ;-)

Comment: @alk Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you just do:

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && i<lim-1)
    s[i++]=c;
```

Your code unnecessarily uses lot of variables which can be avoided by the above loop.

---

[addition by alk]

A more *readable* version:

```
size_t i = 0;
int c = EOF;

...

while (
  ('\n' != (c = getchar())) && 
  (i < lim)
)
{
  s[i] = c;
  ++i;
}
```

Just tiny changes make things better readable, easier to understand, less error prone, more stable.

A less elegant but even more obvious solution:

```
size_t i = 0;

...

while (i < lim)
{
  int c = getchar();
  if ('\n' == c)
  {
    break;
  }

  s[i] = c;
  ++i;
}
```

Comment: Although valid, your code "*unnecessarily*" obsfucate things. The most condensed solution does not need to be the "best".

Comment: You mind me touching your answer?

Comment: Please see my updates to your answer .. ;-)

Comment: With my last proposal there also is the nice side effect that the variable `c`, which is the temporary "read-buffer", is only visible during reading, that is within the loop. Doing so follows the pattern "Do only define what you need."

Comment: I do not see any unnecessary checks. There ought to be even more checks: for example testing for `EOF` is fully missing in your answer.

Comment: Regarding my usage of "*obsfucated*" in this context: http://www.ioccc.org/

Answer (score 0):

This is all that you need to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i=0, j;
  char s[8];
  char c;

  while (i < 8)
  {
    c = getchar();
    if (c == EOF)
      break;
    else if (c != '\n')
      s[i++]=c;
  }

  for (j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    printf("this is the character %c\n",s[j]);

  return 0;
}
```

Loop through for user input (`8 characters max`). When `EOF (Ctrl + D)` is entered by user, the `while loop` will exit and whatever characters entered till that point will be printed as output. If `\n` is given as input, it will be ignored / not saved in the array.